# Lifespan of FluentData IDbContext

Tags: orm, fluentdata

I am using FluentData ORM for .NET in my data access layer. However, this question may apply to most ORMs.

What is the proper lifespan of the IDbContext? Should a new database context be instantiated every time a new query to the database is executed? I have two scenarios below, which is the proper usage? Note that I am querying MS SQL as well as MySQL servers. So, I would like to know if either have any implications as far as reaching the max connections. And yes, I am calling the database on multiple threads. Are both scenarios thread safe?

Scenario A:

My repository class implements IDisposable and holds a private variable of type IDbContext. This variable gets instantiated at the constructor and disposed when the class is disposed. There is only one instance of the context in the repository.

Scenario B:

My repository class has a private method that returns a new instance of IDbContext. Whenever another method makes a call to the database, they call this method to get a new database context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation:

---

**When should you dispose?**

- DbContext must be disposed if you have enabled UseTransaction or
  UseSharedConnection.
- DbCommand must be disposed if you have enabled UseMultiResult (or MultiResultSql).
- StoredProcedureBuilder must be disposed if you have enabled UseMultiResult.

In all the other cases dispose will be handled automatically by FluentData. This means that a database connection is opened just before a query is executed and closed just after the execution has been completed.

---

http://fluentdata.codeplex.com/documentation#Dispose

Hope it helps someone.